# 404 not found on HttpPost from C# in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5.2

I am receiving a 404: not found error when I try to call HasAccess. I use HttpPost to be able to pass a User class because it contains / and \ symbols in some of the strings. This worked as a get but was unable to function because of the extra slashes, so I need to figure out how to make it work as a post or find another way around the \ and / restriction. Here's the response message:

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://localhost/WebServices/Security/api/SecurityCheck/HasAccess/',
Version: 1.1,
Content: System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[[Authorization.Models.User, Authorization, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
Headers:
{
  Accept: application/json
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 118
}}
```

Here is the function declaration in Web API

```
[Route("api/SecurityCheck/HasAccess/")]
[HttpPost]
public bool HasAccess(User current)
{
  if (ValidateUser(current))
  {
    CurrentUser = current;

    return AzMan.Roles.Count != 0;
  }
  return false;
}
```

My Route Configuration in Global.asax

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
  {
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultAPI",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = RouteParameter.Optional });
  });
```

and my call to the Web API function from C#:

```
public async Task executeAsyncPost(string method, int? operationID = null)
{
  try
  {
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SecurityCheckAPI"]);
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

      var user = new User();
      user.UserName = User;
      user.Application = Application;
      user.AuthorizationStore = AuthorizationStore;

      string message = "api/SecurityCheck/" + method + "/";
      if (operationID.HasValue)
      {
        message += operationID.Value.ToString() + "/";
      }

      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(message, user);

      if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
        switch(method)
        {
          case "GetOperationIds":
            _operationIds = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<int[]>();
            break;
          case "GetOperationNames":
            _operationNames = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string[]>();
            break;
          case "CheckAccess":
            _checkAccess = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>();
            break;
          case "HasAccess":
            _hasAccess = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>();
            break;
          case "GetRoles":
            _roles = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object[]>();
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your webapp deployed?  Specifically, how do you account for the "WebServices/Security" section of the URL?

Comment: I realized the error. I forgot to put a slash on the end of the SecurityCheckAPI URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was missing a / at the end of the request Uri. The lack of that / actually removed the entire authorization section from the path and led directly into api.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the final / on the `[Route("api/SecurityCheck/HasAccess/")]` as well as the `RequestUri` itself.

Comment: That did nothing: `RequestUri: 'http://localhost/WebServices/Security/api/SecurityCheck/HasAccess'` stil 404: not found